# Facing issue in react command npm run build

Tags: reactjs, web, create-react-app

Finding the error while running the >>npm run build<<

myapp\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js:664
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
^

TypeError: MiniCssExtractPlugin is not a constructor